# mootools toQueryString of a Form

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

im trieing to serialize a complete form. i found the easiest way:

```
var tmp = $('myForm').toQueryString().parseQueryString();
var req = JSON.decode( tmp );
```

but it wont work.

i testet only

```
var tmp = $('myForm').toQueryString()
alert("data " + tmp);
```

also wont work. it only prints "data " nothing more..

my form is simple:

```
<form action="test.php" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="text" name="user_name">

<input type="submit" name="user_name_button">
</form>
```

the javascript code is like:

```
$('myForm').addEvent( 'submit', function( e ) 
{
  e.stop();
  var tmp = $('myForm').toQueryString()
  alert("data " + tmp);
})
```

does anybody has an idea why this didn work ?

Comment: Works here, http://jsfiddle.net/HXsBk/. Does this example differ from your actual code?

Comment: Above does not work, see answer below instead.

Comment: sry.. that was a mistake.. its just a copy... of my project because of the size..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. The submit and one text field had the same name.

See the fixed version here, http://jsfiddle.net/HXsBk/1/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the many answers.. youre right. but if i try my original in the jsfiddle it works too.. but not local.. :( i dont have ideas :(

Comment: @Roby Then start with this working code and build your local version in steps, just adding small amounts of code, and see in what step that it breaks.